# Get the count of passed days from start of month till today using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does any body know, any method provided by **moment.js** to get the days count that are passed till today (**include current day** too) for the current month.

Let say current days is: **05-03-2020** (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
let count_of_days = moment().getPassedDays()

console.log(count_of_days) // output 5
```

**Some Solutions I tried:**

**1-**

```
let count_of_days = moment().days() + 1
console.log(count_of_days) // 5
```

**2-**

```
let count_of_days = parseInt(moment().format("DD")) + 1
console.log(count_of_days) // 5
```

**3-**

```
let start_of_month = moment().startOf("month")

let curr_day_of_month = moment()

let count_of_days = start_of_month.diff(curr_day_of_month, "days") + 1
console.log(count_of_days) // 5
```

Comment: Today's = passedDaysOfMonth. Then what are your requirements?

Comment: Yes, but I want to get days from moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think date() function return what you're looking for

```
console.log(moment().date()) //  Return 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the documentation, there is no such inbuilt function. 
However, Moment provides a very useful method called diff() that will do your job.

> > First, get the start date of the month.

```
var startDate = moment().startOf('month');
```

> > Secondly, pass your input date till you want the days i.e. in your case its the current day.

```
var endDate = moment(new Date());
```

> > Use diff method()

```
var difference = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
```

> > Since you want the current day as well, add 1 to it and voila! There's your result!

```
var output = difference + 1;
```